# Retrieving Structure of a Binary File

Tags: binary, reverse-engineering, binaryfiles

I have a binary file with .dat file extension. The file belongs to DJI Phantom III drone and created by drone itself. The file contains the all of the flight logs. I need to convert this file to a readable excel file.

Do you know how can i retrieve the data structure of the binary file?

Answer (score 0):

From the [looks of things](https://blog.nvdrones.com/how-to-view-dji-flight-logs-in-4-easy-steps-2e5c6521c6a7), the SDK for .dat log reading is internal to DJI and a few 3rd party developers.  That said, since you're just looking to dump info to an excel, you might not get much more info from the .dat than you would from the .txt log anyway, and you'd get it much faster using one of the existing tools.

If you really really want to get the data structure of the binary file from scratch, get some coffee, a hex reader, and any cryptography breaking skills you can muster, because you're in for a project.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. Actually I don't want to get the data structure but i have to :( There are a few tools created by hobbyists which converts these .dat files. I have a little bit investigated the source codes of the these tools and find out that the .dat files are not encrypted, they are XoR'ed. However the .txt files are encrypted and there are only a few online tools which converts them.